# How to Get Specific Android Documentation Answers

Tags: android, flutter, audio

I'm using audio_session to configure my app like this:

```
  final session = await AudioSession.instance;
  await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration(
    avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playAndRecord,
    avAudioSessionCategoryOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers,
    avAudioSessionMode: AVAudioSessionMode.measurement,
    avAudioSessionSetActiveOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.none,
    androidAudioAttributes: AndroidAudioAttributes(
      contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.sonification,
      flags: AndroidAudioFlags.none,
      usage: AndroidAudioUsage.alarm,
    ),
    androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gainTransient,
    androidWillPauseWhenDucked: true,
  ));
```

In getting answers on iOS settings, it was very easy to get descriptions from the docs.

I do not, however, understand how to get explations of `enum` and `const` values for Android.  For instance:

`androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gainTransient,`

all options: `gain, gainTransient, gainTransientExclusive, gainTransientMayDuck.`

What do these mean and do? [Android docs for AndroidAudioFocusGainType](https://pub.dev/documentation/audio_session/latest/audio_session/AndroidAudioFocusGainType-class.html) do not provide any explanation (making it very hard for audio_session to do any better).

Is this an Android failing, and I have to get used to it, or is there a source of information I'm not aware of?

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/08/respecting-audio-focus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Android docs for AndroidAudioFocusGainType do not provide any explanation (making it very hard for audio_session to do any better)

That is not Android SDK documentation. Off the cuff, it appears to be Flutter documentation.

> Is this an Android failing, and I have to get used to it

The Android SDK appears to have documentation for the constants that map to those Flutter values, such as [`AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_EXCLUSIVE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_EXCLUSIVE).

Comment: Thanks for that!  And yes, silly of me, that's the actual documentation of the package I referenced, I was going too fast.  Can you tell me this--how did you find that developer documentation on AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_EXCLUSIVE?  I searched every way I could.

Comment: @jbryanh: IIRC, initially I searched on `gainTransientExclusive`. That didn't hit on anything directly but got me to `AudioFocusRequest`, where I saw `getFocusGain()` and its possible return values. I agree that ideally that Flutter package's docs would link to the equivalent Android constants. Also, you happen to be a bit lucky in that those constants actually have descriptions in the Android SDK docs -- not all do.